# graphviz error: dot: can't open hello.dot (OSX El Capitan)

Tags: macos, graphviz, osx-elcapitan, dot

I'm trying to install and use graphviz using Mac (El Capitan). As recommended on the graphviz website in the comments, I have installed xcode, xcode command tools, macports and updated macports. I have then installed graphviz via macports using the command

**sudo port install graphviz-gui**

I checked that graphviz installed correctly by typing

**dot -h**

in terminal, and got the response

**$ dot -h**
**dot: option -h unrecognized**

**Usage: dot [-Vv?] [-(GNE)name=val] [-(KTlso)]** 
**...** (etc.)

indicating that the installation was successful.

I then created two test files in text editor (named hello.dot and hello.gv).

When I type

**dot -Tpng -O hello.dot**

in terminal, I get

**Error: dot: can't open hello.dot**

Same with hello.gv

I have also tried opening hello.dot and hello.gv directly with graphviz.app but I get an error window pop-up that says "The document “hello.dot” could not be opened." or "The document “hello.gv” could not be opened."

I have tried restarting terminal and restarting my computer, neither works.

I have downloaded the .pkg installer for the latest version of graphviz, but am afraid to install it in case it interpheres with the macports-installed version of the app. Please can anyone advise if this is the case?

I am *not* great with computers and this is my first time using terminal... so I'm really hoping that there is a really simple, silly thing that I'm doing wrong - I have watched every graphviz youtube tutorial and been through every help page I can find online, with no luck. I am at a loss - I can't figure out what is going wrong and would so appreciate some help - thanks in advance!

Comment: Simple fix: was using TextEdit in rich text format. Any other computer illiterates out there with same problem, simple go to Format -> Make Plain Text, write your dot language for the graph, deselect "if no extension is provided.." and name your file name.gv. In finder, right click name.gv, open with graphviz... TA-DA!

Answer (score 0):

1. Select *hello.dot* file in the Finder window
2. Type Command-I to open an information dialog on *hello.dot*
3. Go down to *Open with:* and select *Graphviz*
4. Also select *Change All...*

That should do it. You can also type *open hello.dot* in the terminal window now. And you don't need Graphviz to be in your PATH.